# Azure Webjobs Static Variables

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

When an Azure webjob is running, listening to an Azure storage queue, will static variables declared in the job remain in memory throughout the lifetime of the webjob (until the webjob is restarted)?  If I declare them in the Functions.cs file - ProcessQueueMessageAsync method, will they remain in memory throughout subsequent queue triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

I didn't find any official doc about it, but it's easy to test it out. Please refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  I suppose I could have done that myself.  Thanks!